# How to convert from array to string glued by colon (,) in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to look the correct way to convert an array to an string but I can't make it to work.

See what I've tried so far:

```php
$arr = [
    ['name' => 'actions',],
    ['width' => 80,],
    ['fixed' => false,],
    ['sortable' => false,],
    ['resize' => false,],
    ['formatter' => 'GridCustomerActions',],
    ['formatoptions' => '',],
    ['index' => 'actions',],
    ['align' => 'left',],
    ['hidden' => false,],
    ['edittype' => false,],
    ['classes' => false,],
    ['editable' => false,],
    ['label' => 'Actions',],
    ['key' => false,]
];

$t1 = json_encode($arr);
echo $t1 . PHP_EOL;

// Output: 
// [{"name":"actions"},{"width":80},{"fixed":false},{"sortable":false},{"resize":false},{"formatter":"GridCustomerActions"},{"formatoptions":""},{"index":"actions"},{"align":"left"},{"hidden":false},{"edittype":false},{"classes":false},{"editable":false},{"label":"Actions"},{"key":false}]

$t2 = implode(',', array_map('reset', $arr));
echo $t2 . PHP_EOL;

// Output: 
// actions,80,,,,GridCustomerActions,,actions,left,,,,,Actions,
```

However the output I am looking for is something like:

```
{"name":"actions","width":80,"fixed":false,"sortable":false,"resize":false,"formatter":"GridCustomerActions","formatoptions":"","index":"actions","align":"left","hidden":false,"edittype":false,"classes":false,"editable":false,"label":"Actions","key":false}
```

This is my array gets built:

```
foreach ($attrs as $name => $default) {
    switch ($name) {
        case 'name':
            $cols[] = [
                'name' => isset($vals[$name]) ? str_replace(' ', '-', $vals[$name]) : ''
            ];
            break;
        case 'width':
            $width  = isset($vals[$name]) ? (int)$vals[$name] : (int)$default;
            $cols[] = ['width' => $width];

            if (!$subgrid) {
                if (isset($vals['hidden']) && $vals['hidden'] === true) {
                    ++$this->width;
                } else {
                    $this->width += ($width + 10);
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'fixed':
            $cols[] = ['fixed' => isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1];
            break;
        case 'sortable':
            $cols[] = ['sortable' => isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1];
            break;
        case 'resize':
            $cols[] = ['resize' => isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1];
            break;
        case 'formatter':
            $cols[] = ['formatter' => $vals[$name] ?? $default];
            break;
        case 'formatoptions':
            $cols[] = ['formatoptions' => $vals[$name] ?? $default];
            break;
        case 'index':
            $cols[] = ['index' => $vals[$name] ?? $default];
            break;
        case 'align':
            $cols[] = ['align' => $vals[$name] ?? $default];
            break;
        case 'hidden':
            $cols[] = ['hidden' => isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1];
            break;
        case 'edittype':
            $cols[] = ['edittype' => isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1];
            break;
        case 'classes':
            $cols[] = ['classes' => $vals[$name] ?? $default];
            break;
        case 'key':
            $cols[] = ['key' => isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1];
            break;
        case 'label':
            $cols[] = ['label' => $vals[$name] ?? $default];
            break;
        case 'editable':
            $cols[] = ['editable' => isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1];
            break;
    }
}
```

Can any give me some ideas?

Comment: Why not just do `echo $t1[0]`? - that should show it as a string. Or do you want to fully convert the array to string?

Comment: The JSON you want doesn't even remotely match the format of your defined array... which is an array of arrays; sort out **how** your specifying that array in the first place.

Comment: Umm..  json_encode($arr[0]); http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php  Id give you the usual speal of google first. .. etc. hardly worth the time though.

Comment: @CD001 I am open to change my array to fit the JSON I am looking for, maybe is how I am building it

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I want to convert the fully array to an string that's the point of the question

Comment: Why don't you just start with an ordinary associative array? `['name' => 'actions', 'width' => 80, ...]`?

Comment: @Barmar - yes but he has a multi-dimensional array so just needs to do `$arr[0]` as the input.

Comment: @ReynierPM - well, if you think you're defining the array wrong in the first place - I've added an answer for that; if that's not what you're after I'll delete it.

Comment: Note the ` json_encode($arr[0])` or `$arr[0]` to unwrap the nesting....  Or am I missing something.  also I have no Idea what this is trying to do `array_map('reset', $arr)`

Comment: Do you have the ability to create your original array in a more logical way? How is that array created?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added such info to the OP

Comment: @ReynierPM - just un-arrayafy these `$cols[] = [ ... ]` so they are simply, `$cols[] = ...`  where you build the array, seems pointless if they have only one element in them.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That won't work. It should be `$cols[$name] = ...`. You can't use `$cols[]` to create an associative array.

Comment: @Barmar - of course you are correct, I was quite tired when I posted that ... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your 2-dimensional array to an associative array:

```
$newArr = [];
foreach ($arr as $sub) {
    foreach ($sub as $key => $val) {
        $newArr[$key] = $val;
    }
}
$t1 = json_encode($newArr);
echo $t1;
```

Or change your original code so it creates an associative array instead of a 2-D array:

```
foreach ($attrs as $name => $default) {
    switch ($name) {
        case 'name':
            $cols['name'] = isset($vals[$name]) ? str_replace(' ', '-', $vals[$name]) : '';
            break;
        case 'width':
            $width  = isset($vals[$name]) ? (int)$vals[$name] : (int)$default;
            $cols['width'] = $width;

            if (!$subgrid) {
                if (isset($vals['hidden']) && $vals['hidden'] === true) {
                    ++$this->width;
                } else {
                    $this->width += ($width + 10);
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'fixed':
            $cols['fixed'] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
            break;
        case 'sortable':
            $cols['sortable'] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
            break;
        case 'resize':
            $cols['resize'] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
            break;
        case 'formatter':
            $cols['formatter'] = $vals[$name] ?? $default;
            break;
        case 'formatoptions':
            $cols['formatoptions'] = $vals[$name] ?? $default;
            break;
        case 'index':
            $cols['index'] = $vals[$name] ?? $default;
            break;
        case 'align':
            $cols['align'] = $vals[$name] ?? $default;
            break;
        case 'hidden':
            $cols['hidden'] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
            break;
        case 'edittype':
            $cols['edittype'] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
            break;
        case 'classes':
            $cols['classes'] = $vals[$name] ?? $default;
            break;
        case 'key':
            $cols['key'] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
            break;
        case 'label':
            $cols['label'] = $vals[$name] ?? $default;
            break;
        case 'editable':
            $cols['editable'] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

There's also lots of similar code in the cases, you could combine them, e.g.:

```
case 'edittype':
case 'key':
case 'editable':
...
    $cols[$name] = isset($vals[$name]) && (int)$vals[$name] === 1;
    break;
```

Comment: I'd go with option 2 *"generating it correctly in the first place"*, but that's a nice quick hack at the start ;)

Comment: @CD001 Your answer seems a whole lot simpler

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = [
    'name' => 'actions',
    'width' => 80,
    'fixed' => false,
    'sortable' => false,
    'resize' => false,
    'formatter' => 'GridCustomerActions',
    'formatoptions' => '',
    'index' => 'actions',
    'align' => 'left',
    'hidden' => false,
    'edittype' => false,
    'classes' => false,
    'editable' => false,
    'label' => 'Actions',
    'key' => false
];
```

That's the actual array structure you want I believe = `json_encode()` should the give you your desired output: https://eval.in/820995

---

Looking at your update, if you want to generate something like that, where you have:

```
$cols[] = [
            'name' => isset($vals[$name]) ? str_replace(' ', '-', $vals[$name]) : ''
        ];
```

That's pushing an array into your array... whereas what you want is to simply push a value onto it at the given index:

```
$cols['name'] = isset($vals[$name]) ? str_replace(' ', '-', $vals[$name]) : '';
```

... and do that sort of thing all the way through.

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = [
    ['name' => 'actions',],
    ['width' => 80,],
    ['fixed' => false,],
    ['sortable' => false,],
    ['resize' => false,],
    ['formatter' => 'GridCustomerActions',],
    ['formatoptions' => '',],
    ['index' => 'actions',],
    ['align' => 'left',],
    ['hidden' => false,],
    ['edittype' => false,],
    ['classes' => false,],
    ['editable' => false,],
    ['label' => 'Actions',],
    ['key' => false,]
];

// create a new object (assoc array) with the correct keys and values
$obj = [];
foreach ($arr as $element) {
  $value = reset($element); // get the first value in the inner array
  $key = key($element);     // get the first key in the inner array
  $obj[$key] = $value;
}

// $obj now contains an assoc array that you can json_encode
$t1 = json_encode($obj);
echo $t1 . PHP_EOL;
```